# How can we download the dynamically generate file from server?

Tags: javascript, servlets, dojo, dijit.form

I want download the file from server (I knew that we can't use AJAX, and serve is Servlet) and which dynamically generate according to the parameters.

Now I have the parameters in format JSON, like:

`{"limitTo":"name","searchFor":["AAA","BBB","CCC"],...}`

So, how can we send the request to the server with those paraleters? Do we need create some `input`s?

Comment: try using window.open(url?limitTo='name'&searchFor='["AAA","BBB","CCC"]' .....)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the solution which uses `dojo/request/iframe`, without `window.open`

And the code likes :

```
require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframe){
  // cancel the last request
  iframe._currentDfd = null;
  iframe("something.xml", {
    handleAs: "xml",
    data : "your json"
  }).then(function(xmldoc){
    // Do something with the XML document
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  });
  // Progress events are not supported using the iframe provider
});
```

And then we can see download window.

[Here](http://www.mikejuniper.com/fun-with-dojoioiframesend/) is an article about `dojo/request/iframe`